# Erro na biblioteca DHT

Tags: arduino

Sempre que tento carregar a biblioteca `DHT` me retorna este erro, até hoje não consegui fazer meu `dht22` funcionar.

> In file included from C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.cpp:22:0:
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\libraries\DHT-sensor-library-master\DHT_U.h:25:29: fatal
>   error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory
>
> #include "Adafruit_Sensor.h"

Comment: Já seguiu os passos deste [link](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/issues/62)?

Comment: Consegui estava faltando a biblioteca. Baixei e problema resolvido. VLW Ismael.                                                                                 Adafruit_Sensor.h  $ARDUINO_HOME$/libraries/Adafruit_Sensor/Adafruit_Sensor.h.